# Count outgoing links in adjacency list graph representation in C

Tags: c

I have a graph with adjacency list representation and want to find how many outgoing links each vertices has. I created a function to count nodes of linked list at a specific vertex, however, after calling count function, all nodes (edges) of this vertex are being removed from the graph (at least I'm not able to display them). How can I fix this?

Graph output of vertices and edges without calling count function:

```
Vertex 0: 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 
Vertex 1: 4 -> 
Vertex 2: 6 -> 1 -> 5 -> 4 -> 
Vertex 3: 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 0 -> 
Vertex 4: 6 -> 2 -> 1 -> 
Vertex 5: 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 6 -> 4 -> 1 -> 
Vertex 6: 0 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1 ->
```

After counting number of edges for vertex 4:

```
Outgoing links: 3

Vertex 0: 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 
Vertex 1: 4 -> 
Vertex 2: 6 -> 1 -> 5 -> 4 -> 
Vertex 3: 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 0 -> 
Vertex 4: 
Vertex 5: 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 6 -> 4 -> 1 -> 
Vertex 6: 0 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1 ->
```

Graph structure:

```
typedef struct graph {
    int numberV;
    int numberE;
    struct vertex **adjList;
} GraphT; 

typedef struct vertex {
    int vertex;
    struct vertex *next; 
} VertexT;
```

Code for counting:

```
int countLinks(GraphT *graph, int vertex) {
    int count = 0;
    GraphT *current = graph;
    while (current->adjList[vertex] != NULL) {
        count++;
        current->adjList[vertex] = current->adjList[vertex]->next;
    }
    return count; 
}

int main () {
    ...
    int c = countLinks(graph, 4); 
    printf("Outgoing links: %d\n", c); 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all nodes (edges) of this vertex are being removed from the graph (at
> least I'm not able to display them)

That's because you are updating and setting the pointer to `NULL`  at the very end:

```
int countLinks(GraphT *graph, int vertex) {
    int count = 0;
    GraphT *current = graph;
    while (current->adjList[vertex] != NULL) {
        count++;
        current->adjList[vertex] = current->adjList[vertex]->next; //here
    }
    return count; 
}
```

try

```
int countLinks(GraphT *graph, int vertex) {
    int count = 0;
    GraphT *current = graph;
    struct vertex *temp;

    temp = current->adjList[vertex];
    while (temp != NULL) {
        count++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return count; 
}
```